# Contact Form 7 multiple form on same page not working on ajax submit

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

There are 2 forms submitting through ajax on same page, using contact form 7 plugin shortcode.
Also there are 3 fields which has same name in both forms, so i add different classes on these fields in both forms.
However they still not working , when i click submit button on any of the form both form, then both submit button shows submitting text on them and diabled. any idea

->

https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-prevent-multi-submit-on-contact-form-7/

Comment: We can't fix descriptions, show your code please

Comment: this is scenario, basically in wordpress all these work done through editors where you place shortcodes, and this will not help .

Comment: Well you're going to need to show us _something_ relevant. Right now your question is the equivalent of phoning a mechanic and asking them to fix your car without looking in the engine

Comment: i have updated my question with the link, you can get the idea of my issue from that link as well, please check

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Posting an external link doesn't qualify (they can change or die). Post the code which _your_ site is running, inside _your_ question.Thanks

Comment: P.S. If you think the problem is exclusive to the code created by this plugin, then speaking to the plugin maintainer should be your first step really.